# How do I see the contents of the file in fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

Im trying to see the actual files that have been sniffed by fiddler. So I have a load of session and in them is for example some .js files. But when I click on the entry in fiddler I cannot seem to see the actual file. When I click 'textview' I just see a black green screen at the bottom right hand side of the GUI.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "Black green screen"? What Inspector are you looking at? Is there a yellow bar indicating that the response needs to be decompressed?

Comment: Is the .js file really downloaded in that particular request you are analysing in fiddler (http-result 200 and not 304 Not modified -> see. tab "Headers"?) Is there an encoding/ compression (normally that shold be signalled by the golden bar above the response-pane)

Answer (score 0):

May be the text color is same as background color so you cannot see them.

Menu >> Tools >> Fiddler Options >> Appearance >> Set Readonly Color, then choose a white color.